# My HP ProBook shuts down abnormally and doesn't start again for some time

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop autoshutdown problem?](https://superuser.com/questions/331194/laptop-autoshutdown-problem)

I have a HP ProBook 4520s with Windows 7, and I played Company of Heroes for the first time. My charger was plugged out, I got the sound of battery being low and plugged in the charger while I was already playing the game.

After some time, my system shut down abnormally. Usually, if it's low on battery charge, it hibernates. I think it was too heated up.

A friend suggested to remove its battery and insert it again, so I did that and it started working again, being charged a bit.

I'd like to find out if my system was heated up too much, so that it eventually shut down the laptop, just like when you plug out a desktop PC. This happened to me two times before. Here in Pakistan, weather forecast says it's 31° C at this time. Was this a heat problem?

Should I avoid playing games too? How can I find out what happened?

Comment: I would like to mention that my OS is 64bit so can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very similar to this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/331194/laptop-autoshutdown-problem/) There are several tools to monitor your system temperature and see if it's overheating. You can also try cleaning out the vents.

Comment: thanks, however after reading the link you gave, I think it is because of some incompatibility because due to heat, my system normally hanged in summer. And there is now many time I used system and I think it also heated up while doing other things but this only happen while playing "company of heroes". So do you think that this can be such problem?

Comment: @OldWolf - I think SU needs a "Did you try cleaning the vents out?" button. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check your system log after you turn it back on. Generally there will a report saying why the system shut down.

- Right click on computer, select Manage.
- In the left hand side, Under System tools select event viewer, windows logs, system.
- Look at the information until you find the message from just after you booted up or just before it shut down. That should give you some solid information to go off of to figure out why the system is shutting down on you. It could be some sort of driver conflict, could be the heating up factor that you suspect, or something else entirely.

Comment: thanks, but these text don't match , I just saw the screen when it says start windows normally after starting system again, but that info isn't found in logs where you said

Comment: No no, the screen I'm talking about is after you log into windows. The screen you're describing happens before the system is done booting. My instructions are for after you have logged into windows. You'll have to look at the timestamps of the events that occur to find where/why the crash is happening.